# What are these Yu-Gi-Oh! cards and which anime characters are holding them?

Tags: object-identification, yu-gi-oh

This picture shows ten people holding *Yu-Gi-Oh!* cards, and I presume they are all from the anime series.

[image: Ten hands holding different Yu-Gi-Oh! cards]

The ones in the front are Blue Eyes White Dragon and Dark Magician, and the sleeves make it seem like they are being held by Seto Kaiba and Yugi Moto respectively, both of whom are from the original anime.

What are the rest of these *Yu-Gi-Oh!* cards and which anime characters are holding them?

Comment: Please tell us where and when you found this image, because the context can help with such questions.

Comment: @b_jonas A Pinterest collection. So unfortunately, not much context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, they are indeed the 'rivals' and protagonists of past Yu-Gi-Oh! series and the monster cards most commonly associated with them. Those from VRAINS are absent. Here is the list, from top-to-bottom:

On the left:

- [Declan Akaba](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Declan_Akaba), one of the 'rival' characters from Yu-Gi-Oh! Arc-V holding [D/D/D Doom King Armageddon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/D/D/D_Doom_King_Armageddon).
- [Kite Tenjo](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Kite_Tenjo), the rival of Yu-Gi-Oh! Zexal holding [Galaxy-Eyes Photon Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Galaxy-Eyes_Photon_Dragon).
- [Jack Atlas](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Jack_Atlas), the rival of Yu-Gi-Oh! 5Ds holding his [Red Dragon Archfiend](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Dragon_Archfiend).
- [Chazz Princeton](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Chazz_Princeton) from Yu-Gi-Oh! GX holding [Armed Dragon Lv10](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Armed_Dragon_LV10).
- [Seto Kaiba](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Seto_Kaiba) from the original Yu-Gi-Oh! series holding [Blue-Eyes White Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon).

On the right:

- [Yuya Sakaki](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yuya_Sakaki), the protagonist of Arc-V holding [Odd-Eyes Pendulum Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Odd-Eyes_Pendulum_Dragon) (originally [Odd-Eyes Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Odd-Eyes_Dragon)).
- [Yuma Tsukomo](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yuma_Tsukumo), the protagonist of Zexal holding [Number 39: Utopia](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Number_39:_Utopia).
- [Yusei Fudo](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yusei_Fudo), the protagonist of 5Ds holding [Stardust Dragon](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Stardust_Dragon).
- [Jaden Yuki](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Jaden_Yuki), the protagonist of GX holding [Elemental Hero/HERO Neos](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Elemental_HERO_Neos).
- [Yami Yugi](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yami_Yugi), one of the main characters from the original Yu-Gi-Oh! series holding [Dark Magician](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Magician).